# How to add single quotes around query string using jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, query-string, wcf-data-services

I'm using `jqGrid` to display some data to users. I want this grid to be sortable, but the data jqGrid sends isn't exactly what I need.

Here is the query string jqGrid sends now:

```
http://local/MyService.svc/GetData?_search=false&nd=1313069918597&rows=50&page=1&sidx=ColumnName&sord=asc
```

But my service needs it to be:

```
http://local/MyService.svc/GetData?_search=false&nd=1313069918597&rows=50&page=1&sidx='ColumnName'&sord='asc'
```

Notice the single quotes around `ColumnName` and `asc`

There are tons of jqGrid options and I haven't found anything that allows me to manipulate the querystring parameters in this way. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [serializeGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event/parameter of jqGrid which can help you solve any problems of customization of the server requests. In your case the [serializeGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) could looks as following

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    var myPostData = $.extend({}, postData); // make a copy of the input parameter
    myPostData.sidx = "'" + myPostData.sidx + "'";
    myPostData.sord = "'" + myPostData.sord + "'";
    return myPostData;
}
```