# How to change sidx,sord,filters parameters names in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

If column names are sidx,sord,filters , jqGrid getting data is broken. I tried to add underscores to them using code below but those parameters are still passed without underscores. Other parameters like _rowid, _page etc. are passed properly with underscores.

How to use sidx,sord,filters  as column names in jqgrid ?

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    prmNames: { id: "_rowid", oper: "_oper", page: "_page",
        sidx: "_sidx", sord: "_sord", page: "_page", rows: "_rows", filters: "_filters"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean under "If column names are sidx,sord,filters , jqGrid getting data is broken". Nevertheless if you need you can rename or remove the jqGrid parameters with two ways: `prmNames` and `serializeGridData`.

You should carefully examine the list of default values of the [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). There are no possibility to rename `filters` in the way, but to rename the name of other parameters you should use

```
$.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    prmNames: {
        id: "_rowid", page: "_page", rows: "_rows",
        oper: "_oper", sort: "_sidx", order: "_sord"
    }
});
```

(`sort` and `order` instead of `sidx` and `sord`). To rename `filters` to `_filters` and to remove sending of empty `searchField`, `searchString` and `searchOper` you can do almost the same what I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027075/how-to-add-single-quotes-around-query-string-using-jqgrid/7032402#7032402):

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    var myPostData = $.extend({}, postData); // make a copy of the input parameter
    myPostData._filters = myPostData.filters;
    delete myPostData.filters;
    delete myPostData.searchField;
    delete myPostData.searchString;
    delete myPostData.searchOper;
    return myPostData;
}
```

Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can verify that in the URL of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/prmNamesUsage.htm) are used the following parameters

```
_search=true&nd=1313235583212&_rows=10&_page=1&_sidx=invdate&_sord=desc&_filters=...
```

like you as need.