# jqGrid - cant select rows - Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: select, jqgrid, row, jqgrid-asp.net, typeerror

Thanks to Oleg, my jqGrid now looks like this, and works fine. (my problem after the code)

```
var columnModel = [{ name: 'ID', index: 'ID', sortable: true, summaryType:'count', summaryTpl:'<b>{0} Item(s)</b>' },
{ name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', sortable: true},
{ name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', sortable: true }
];
var columnNames = ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'];

myGrid.jqGrid({
    url: './WebService.asmx/ViewNQueryData',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
        total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
    },
    colModel: columnModel,
    colNames: columnNames,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 300],
    sortname: 'ID',
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#ViewNQueryPager",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: 250,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['ID'],
        groupColumnShow: [false],
        groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
        groupSummary: [true],
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        groupDataSorted: true,
        showSummaryOnHide: true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    gridComplete: function () {
        $('#totalRecordsFound').html(myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + " Customers");
    },
    onSelectRow: function () { alert("selected"); }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#ViewNQueryPager', 
                { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: true },//option
                {}, // use default settings for edit
                {}, // use default settings for add
                {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
                {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true, onSearch: function (response) { showQueryDetails(); } },
                {height: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true} // view options
                );
myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true });
```

For some odd reason i can select any row (evrything else works fine) and i get in the browser this exception:

This happens only in chrome, firefox works fine.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
$.jgrid.extend.setSelection
e.extend.eachjquery-1.6.2.min.js:16
e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.6.2.min.js:16
$.jgrid.extend.setSelection
$.fn.jqGrid
$.fn.jqGrid.each.$.before.click.bind.ts.p.datatype
f.event.handlejquery-1.6.2.min.js:17
f.event.add.i.handle.k
```

I need some new eyes to please help me and see what i did wrong... this is really driving me crazy..

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My JSON data is like:

```
{"d":{"__type":"JqGridData","total":3,"page":1,"records":24,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","Prabir","Shrestha"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","Scott","Gu"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Scott","Gu"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Bill","Gates"]},{"id":5,"cell":["5","Steve","Ballmer"]},{"id":1,"cell":["1","Prabir","Shrestha"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","Scott","Gu"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Scott","Hanselman"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Bill","Hanselman"]},{"id":5,"cell":["5","Steve","Ballmer"]}]}}
```

Comment: Could you include test JSON data which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Oleg,Wow, thanks for the quick response. how can i get the JSON data?

Comment: @Oleg, another weird problem i have is that even that i am using the multipleSearch option sometimes the regular search opens up, could that be connected??

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch HTTP traffic.

Comment: @Oleg, I just tested my site in firefox, and i can select with no problem, only on chrome it gives me that problem. did you ever come across with something like that? I edited my question with the JSON data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of your problem is the inconsistent JSON data which you use:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "JqGridData",
        "total": 3,
        "page": 1,
        "records": 24,
        "rows": [
            {"id": 1, "cell": ["1", "Prabir", "Shrestha"]},
            {"id": 2, "cell": ["2", "Scott", "Gu"]},
            {"id": 3, "cell": ["3", "Scott", "Gu"]},
            {"id": 4, "cell": ["4", "Bill", "Gates"]},
            {"id": 5, "cell": ["5", "Steve", "Ballmer"]},
            {"id": 1, "cell": ["1", "Prabir", "Shrestha"]},
            {"id": 2, "cell": ["2", "Scott", "Gu"]},
            {"id": 3, "cell": ["3", "Scott", "Hanselman"]},
            {"id": 4, "cell": ["4", "Bill", "Hanselman"]},
            {"id": 5, "cell": ["5", "Steve", "Ballmer"]}
        ]
    }
}
```

The `id` filed will be used as the value of `id` attribute of rows of the grid (`<tr>` elements). Corresponds to HTML/XHTML specification **ids must be unique on the page**.

Comment: @Oleg - This also turned out to be the solution to a problem I was having, so thanks!