# jqgrid custom ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use jqgrid with an existing REST framework for querying and filtering data.

Is there a way in jqgrid to customize the ajax request data/parameters?  It looks like you can set the `url` and `mtype (ie. GET, POST)`, but I'm not sure how to set the parameter data.  The REST API I'm using has it's own filtering and sorting syntax.  I would need to convert the param data from jqgrid into a format that is usable by the REST API.

For reference, I'm thinking of something similar to this https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax (the function form of the option), where you are able to make the ajax request yourself and pass the results to a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize properties of `jQuery.ajax` one can use `ajaxGridOptions` parameter. To customize Ajax call used for loading of the grid one can use `serializeGridData` callback. The `serializeGridData` callback get object with the parameters which will be send by default (like `data` parameter of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). The value, returned from the callback, will be used as `data` parameter of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). You can find examples of an implementation of `serializeGridData` in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979809/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7032402/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584574/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811359/315935) and many other.